# Eigen Vector cout problems

Tags: c++, eigen

i am using

```
Eigen::Vector2d vector(1,2)
std::cout << "x" << vector[0] << std::endl;
```

but this is not working because of invalid overload of cout

But this value should be double or?

```
Eigen::Vector2d vector(1,2)
double x = vector[0]
std::cout << "x" << x << std::endl;
```

this works... anyone know why ? Or what i have to do to get the double value back ?

thanks for help

Comment: Your first code snippet compiles fine for me (if I add the missing semicolon). Can you give as a minimal, but complete example that gives the error you describe? While you're at it, include the exact error message and the version of Eigen.

Comment: the first snipped is not working ? Ok i tried it now ...  i get the error on eclipse as "invalid overload" i only read this ... builind and output is fine ... do u know why eclipse show this error?

Comment: My guess would be that eclipse's code analysis backend is not good enough to catch all the intricacies of a complicated template library like Eigen.

Comment: As us2012 said, Eclipse cannot fully parse C++. However for small fixed  size vectors you can use the x(), y(), z(),w() operators. So cout << vector.x() << endl; shows no semantic errors in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the result of `vector[0]` is not `double`? Maybe it's some class or a custom type? In the first snippet you've explicitly converted `vector[0]` to `double`. If that case, try casting the result in the second snippet:

```
Eigen::Vector2d vector(1,2);
std::cout << "x" << (double)(vector[0]) << std::endl;
```